# VBA skips cells when data is entered

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an issue with my VBA code, maybe someone can explain where I made a mistake and how can it be fixed.
My goal is to create 7 columns without skipping cells.
I have 7 text boxes but not all of them has to be filled every time data is entered.
At the moment when data is added only in Name text box it creates new row but when only surname is added it skips first empty lines and enters diagonally under Name entry(as in attachment) [Excel img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlbpH.png)

Also there is a mistake when I want to add entry in other text boxes, entered data is just moved around.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim LR As Long

   LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

   Cells(LR, 1).Value = Name.Value
   Cells(LR, 2).Value = Surname.Value
   Cells(LR, 3).Value = Address.Value
   Cells(LR, 4).Value = Phone.Value
   Cells(LR, 5).Value = City.Value
   Cells(LR, 6).Value = Car.Value
   Cells(LR, 7).Value = Job.Value

   Name.Value = ""
   Surname.Value = ""
   Address.Value = ""
   Phone.Value = ""
   City.Value = ""
   Car.Value = ""
   Job.Value = ""


End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like it does what you want tho? Or where should the number in column B be? You are counting the last row in column A. If you want to know the last row of column B you need to change the LR line into `...cells(Rows.count, 2)...`. You could also leave that line out completely and ... too much to do here, see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always looking for the last row in column A, thats why it adds the surname one row below the last row of column A. If you want to know the last row of another column, you need to change the 1 after Rows.Count into the corresponding number. You can also do this in one line, have a gander:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = Name.Value
   Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2).Value = Surname.Value
   Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3).Value = Address.Value
   Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 4).Value = Phone.Value
   Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5).Value = City.Value
   Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 6).Value = Car.Value
   Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 7).Value = Job.Value

   Name.Value = ""
   Surname.Value = ""
   Address.Value = ""
   Phone.Value = ""
   City.Value = ""
   Car.Value = ""
   Job.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: How it's possible to save this file for example in Temp folder and after it's edited, there is just auto-save? Should I have also Save button on my program where I can add code for saving or it can be done without saving button and every time data is entered it auto-saves?